# Discord.js searching on key terms

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I'm trying to create a Discord bot for trading within certain games. So far I have most of the basic commands working--!create creates a trade listing in an SQL database, !find finds one--but it only finds it on the exact same word. What I'm trying to do is make the search less specific so the terms don't have to be exactly equal to show results.
My current code is pretty convoluted and, needless to say, very broken:

```
var searchTerms = args[1].split(" ");
var output = {};
for (var id in userData) {
    for (var offer in userData[id].offers) {
        var score = 0;
        for (var key in searchTerms) {
            if (offer.includes(key)) {
                score ++;
            }
        }
        if (score >= searchTerms.length / 2) {
            output[id] = userData[id].offers[offer] + " - " + ((score / searchTerms.length) * 100) + "%";
        }
    }
}
if (output == {}) {
    bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'No matching offers found.'
    });
} else {
    msg = ""
    for (id in output) {
        msg += '<@' + id + '> - ' + output[id] + "   "
    }
    bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: Object.keys(output).length + ' offers found: ' + msg
    });
}
```

I'm new to Javascript so I'm not really sure how to get this working. Any tips are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to implement is an mechanism called `Fuzzy Search`, which user can find similar results using typo or approximate strings.

( Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching )

It not really an easy feature for a programming beginner to implement on your own, either the database have to support some kind of fuzzy query, or you'll have to get all the data from database first, and use a JavaScript fuzzy search library to accomplish that.

If you still want to do it, I recommend using [Fuse.js](http://fusejs.io/), which is able to accomplish fuzzy search in a few lines

```
//list to be searched
var books = [{
  'ISBN': 'A',
  'title': "Old Man's War",
  'author': 'John Scalzi'
}, {
  'ISBN': 'B',
  'title': 'The Lock Artist',
  'author': 'Steve Hamilton'
}]
```

---

```
// init the search
var options = {
  keys: ['title', 'author'],
  id: 'ISBN'
}
var fuse = new Fuse(books, options)

fuse.search('old')
```

---

```
// result
[
  "A"
]
```

Fuzzy search is a complex computer science problem, if you want to know more about it and how Fuse.js is implemented, here are a few useful links

- [An intro to fuzzy string matching](https://medium.com/@julientregoat/an-introduction-to-fuzzy-string-matching-178805cca2ab)
- [source code of Fuse.js](https://github.com/krisk/fuse)
- [bitap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm) (used by fuse.js)

Comment: So how should this be implemented in my case? I have an sql dictionary of user IDs and then for each ID an array of attributes--currently the only one is an array "offers" that contains a list of offers. So should I iterate over each user's array of offers and then search that with Fuse?